# Knowledge of Linux for Android

Tags: android, linux

Can someone tell me why Linux knowledge is needed for Android jobs ?
Many of the Android jobs have Linux as a prerequisite.
I can very well develop an Android app from a Windows machine right ?

Comment: You would be (potentially) developing on a windows machine but targetting linux machines. Knowledge of the linux ecosystem will make your life much easier.

Comment: Maybe because android is linux-based...

Answer (score 3):

I would say it might be because they prefer to work on Linux and thus you need at least to know the basic installation of the Android Tooling (SDK, eclipse etc..).

On the other hand Android is based on Linux Kernel and uses some UNIX conventions. A knowledge of how things works is a plus. Processes, commands, packaging are among the ones you should know.
You don't have to be a Linux guru to know this.

But still i believe the most important is the knowledge of Android development which is the same for all platforms.

Answer (score 1):

Android uses DVM (Dalvik Virtual Machine) which is based on linux kernel at the bottom. Hence to have the idea about linux helps in developing android application. You can develop android applications on windows OS as well using android SDK.